# Write all elements of A.A = {$x|x^2<x<10$,x is a whole number}. Answer: A ={$x|x^2+1=0$}.Explain like i'm five.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Write all elements of A.A = {$x|x^2<x<10$,x is a whole number}.

Given Answer: A ={$x|x^2+1=0$}.

Is this a typo?

Comment: Don't write the answer in the title! Try to **describe** it in the title and write it down, with all your work, in the body of the answer.

Comment: I don't understand the given answer and wanted someone to explain it.No idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A is the set of reals integers $x$ such that $x^2<x<10$.

$x^2<x$ is equivalent to $0<x<1,1<10$.

Thus there is no integer ('whole number') solution.

This is coherent with the given answer since no real number (be it integer or not) verifies $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: While this is true, why not just say $A = \varnothing$?

Comment: @molarmass I'm not sure, since it's equivalent.

Comment: @molarmass: I suspect it was a multiple-choice question: Which of these sets is equal to $A$?

Comment: That makes sense.